# Why is rails 3.2 allowing duplicate records despite validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, validation, activerecord

I am using Rails 3.2 and I am using Postgresql. I have a button that updates a QuestionRecords table with a record. This table stores the user_id and a question_id and a couple of other bits of information. On the model I have the following validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :question_id
```

Strangely, it has twice enabled exactly the same record to be inserted into the database despite this validation. This corrupts an algorithm I am using so is a bit of a disaster.

Firstly, why is this happening; and secondly, how can I prevent it beyond the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Race conditions. App side validation is a two step process. First a query is made that checks for existing records. If none are found, app proceeds with saving. It can happen that two (or more) app threads perform the check, both get positive results and both proceed to inserting data.

> How can I prevent it beyond the validation?

You should enforce uniqueness at database level. This is as simple as creating a unique index on `(question_id, user_id)`.